# Where Statement from declared variable Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

it's possible to pass a Where statement through declared variable in SQL Server 2008?, How can I do something like this?

```
declare @foo as nvarchar(max) = '9510,9580,5030'
SELECT T1.[ItemCode]
FROM tbl1 T1
WHERE T1.ItemCode in (@foo)
```

When I run this code my foo variable can hold at least one item or 100 items, that depends on another result

Comment: [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381780/679449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using exec.

```
declare @foo as nvarchar(max) = '9510,9580,5030'

declare @SQLString as nvarchar(max)
set @SQLString  = 'SELECT T1.[ItemCode]
                   FROM tbl1 T1
                   WHERE T1.ItemCode in (' + @foo + ')'
exec (@SQLString )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use table variable:

```
DECLARE @foo AS NVARCHAR(max) = 'yourstring'

DECLARE @SQLString table (name NVARCHAR(max))

    INSERT INTO @SQLString
    SELECT T1.[ItemCode]
    FROM tbl1 T1
    WHERE T1.ItemCode LIKE ('%' + @foo + '%')

SELECT * FROM @SQLString
```